# Cross Field Matching Rule - Duplicate Rules

Tags: contact, duplicate-management, matcher, dupeblocker

On Contact record we have two email fields - Email and Personal_Email__c. We want to identify records as matches if any of the email address fields match any existing email addresses in those fields in the database. Currently, you can only match each field to itself within the database using Contact Matching Rules.We got 500K Contacts in Salesforce and 110K Contacts has email addresses.

Duplicate rules won't support cross field matching.There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cHBJAA2) for it.Any workaround for this.

Comment: As there is no way(as far as I know) we can use Duplicate Rules across the  different fields, you might need to consider using **Triggers** here. Throw an alert box or a customized modal window to let the end user know that there is a Contact already exists in the Org.

Comment: And if you are looking for just identifying the matching records based on emails, you can build a VF page(that sits on Contact detail page) and have SOSL to get a global search functionality to identify possible duplicates(with the same email address).